# Stack Overflow question ban after getting up-votes

Tags: discussion, post-ban

So, I sadly got a question ban in Stack Overflow, however, it is unclear to me why... I have read through everything that I could find in the Help Center. It seems to me that I have a permanent ban and am strongly and sadly considering closing my account as a result (which is quite a hassle). The only reason that I am posting this question, is because I got the ban the morning after getting up-votes for some of my questions. Am I being punished for getting irregular up-votes? If so, the system seems like it needs a bit of tweaking...

So, did I really do something wrong, and what should I do?

Comment: You didn't get banned because of anything else but you have a history of asking poor quality questions.  Given the lack of negative posts visible in your profile, one can only assume you have several deleted posts with multiple downvotes.  If you read through [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th?rq=1) you will know that deleted posts still count against you.

Comment: You may very well (probably) be right, however I am still confused why it happened *right* after getting up-votes.